# gulp.watch trigger only when files are added or deleted but not changed

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I want to fire off a task only when files are added or deleted but not changed.

I have the watch

```
gulp.watch(['src/App/**/*.js', 'src/**/*.css'], ['inject']);
```

But this triggers an inject every time I change a file, I only want to trigger an inject when I add or delete a file. I can't seem to find any way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
gulp.task('watch',function(){
    gulp.watch(['src/App/**/*.js', 'src/**/*.css'],function(event){
        if(event.type === 'added' || event.type === 'deleted'){
            console.log('file was added or deleted!');
        }   
    })
})
```

If you want to run tasks registered only when watched file are added or deleted. such as:

```
gulp.watch(['src/App/**/*.js', 'src/**/*.css'], ['inject']);
```

**As far as I know, there is no way to achieve this.**